# Fixed position for navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

In Apple's calendar app, when you add a new event the navigation bar at the top remains fixed and the content slides under it:

[image]

I'd like to replicate that behavior, but I can't get it to work. I'm using `UITableViewController`, and my table is going under the `UINavigationBar`
(See first record "Gnn").

Answer (score 1):

Use this to show your view controller and it will be give you fixed Nav bar.

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(MyViewController(), animated:true)
```

[image: Fixed Navigation]

Comment: I'm not sure if there isn't a misunderstanding. I want the navigation bar of "Second View" to be fixed. Is that what you're describing here?

Comment: use `navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController(), animated:true)` to show second view.

Comment: Hmm. I think we did misunderstand each other. I don't want the green view controller. ;) I want the content (the table view) **to slide under** the navigation bar. Have a look at my picture, please. The Gnn is cut off. That's what I want. Appreciate your effort. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah, Misunderstanding. Can you please add the constraints of your tableview

Comment: Hm? My table view is a TableViewController. It doesn't have constraints, does it?

Comment: Then how you setup TableViewController in this view?.

Comment: I used a UITableViewController, not a UITableView on a UIViewController. It's automatically set up.

Comment: But you just gave me an idea and I think I fixed it. :) Thanks! I will write up the solution later, when I'm certain it works.